# Change the content of a XAML object from a different class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to call a none static function in class `MainWindow` but the problem is when I create an instance of the `MainWindow` class in another class, the application window stops launching.

So how can I call a function without creating an instance of `MainWindow`? To edit the conten of a label or any other attribute of a XAML object.

Some examples will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to change the content or an attribute value of a XAML object, then I'd recommend you look at `DataBinding` and MVVM.  If you are using `DataBinding`, you don't need to concern yourself with the XAML or the `MainWindow` at all - you just change a property value on the `DataContext` or ViewModel and the change is automatically reflected in the view (in this case, the `MainWindow`).

Multiple classes can have a reference to this object (your ViewModel or `DataContext` object) and can make changes to properties and have those changes reflected in the view.  It is hard to give examples without a clearer picture of what you're trying to do.  Perhaps if you provide some example code or show what you've attempted, I can use that to create an example.

For more reading on MVVM and DataBinding, you can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), but there are tons of resources out there.